# 404 on all routes after applying SSL on Laravel 5 Project

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I've Deployed my project on the server. It's working fine on the `http` but when I apply SSL certificate, and try to access URLs with `https` it shows `404` error.

I'm trying to find the solution since hours but no success. Here's my .htaccess file.

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://serveravatar.com/%$1 [R,L]

</IfModule>
```

I am unable to find the Mistake. I also tried editing AppServiceProvider but no success!

Comment: Shouldn't the HTTPS conditions come before the Laravel rules? Additionally, you don't need to declare RewriteEngine On twice. And you don't need that percent before $1 in the HTTPS redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @SArnab said is correct, move it before your standard rules. Also, a better way of writing the rule would be:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```